# How does Windows 10 deal with a file renamed with an invalid character through the C++ rename function?

Tags: c++, rename

I was writing some code to rename a list of files in a folder when, by mistake, I wrote the invalid character "\" in the new name.

Even if the new name was then invalid for Windows, the rename function actually renamed the file, so that the original one disappeared from the folder. Unfortunately, I cannot find the file with the new name, since it seems to not have been created or accepted by Windows.
Does anyone know how to restore or retrieve the original file?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: As requested, here follows an example of the code: this one is actually simpler and the mistake is obvious, but the problem is the same. ("test.txt" seems to disappear once renamed with the invalid filename "\test.txt").

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string>
#include<windows.h>
#include<dirent.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

string ExePath();

string ExePath() {
    char buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName( NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH );

    string::size_type pos = string( buffer ).find_last_of( "\\/" );
    return string( buffer ).substr( 0, pos);
}

int main (){
DIR *dir;
struct dirent *ent;
    if ((dir = opendir (ExePath().c_str())) != NULL) {
        string oldname("test.txt");
        string newname("\\test.txt"); //invalid filename
        rename(oldname.c_str(),newname.c_str()); //the function doesn't return any error message
        closedir(dir);
    }
    else {
  perror ("");
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @MikeMB `rename` is in ISO C (and therefore ISO C++ by inclusion)

Comment: `string newname("\\test.txt"); //invalid filename` Remember that rename will also move. test.text should be in the root folder of the current drive unless UAC prevented the move. By default c:\ should require a UAC elevation.

Comment: You should check the return value of `rename` and, if not 0, lookup the error code (which I believe is implementation defined).

Comment: My guess would be, the file is getting moved to the root of the current drive. `rename()` is likely a simple wrapper around `MoveFile`. `\test.txt` is a valid relative path. Indeed, [MSDN documentation on `rename`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw5t957f.aspx) says: "You can use `rename` to move a file from one directory or device to another by giving a different path in the `newname` argument."

Comment: @M.M: Right, totally forgot about that - shame over me ;) prahken: Sorry!

Comment: @IgorTandetnik If the "\" character is seen as a valid relative path, this means that I should be able to locate a file named "test.txt" in some folder.. Am I wrong ? The problem is that I cannot find such a file in any folder, not even by searching "\test.txt" or "test.txt" in the whole computer. The file seems then to be missing, but if I create a new "test.txt" file and use the program again, this time I get an error from rename, stating that a file named "\test.txt" already exists. The problem is still unsolved: how can I locate the (missing) renamed file? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try to open `%LOCALAPPDATA%\VirtualStore` location in windows explorer. Maybe your move got virtualized there.